# conditionalPanel Behavior in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app with multiple conditional panels. The app works as desired when I run it locally. However when you run it from a server, all conditional panels appear, the moment the app is launched. I am not sure what might be the reason for this behavior. Can someone point me in the right direction? I don't even know what to check for/modify? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Any warnings in the logs ? I faced it with a dateInput that as `""` value instead of NULL, might be the same

Comment: @ Clemsang - There is no dateInput in my app :(

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example?

Comment: @ DeltaKappa - Could I email it to you? It is a very long ui and the only one where conditional Panels are behaving weirdly. I

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I found out that multiple conditions inside the conditionalPanel are not working on the server. They work correctly on my machine but not on the server. Hopefully, this will help someone else struggling with the same issue. I do not know why this would happen but for now the problem is resolved.